# Divide by 6 hours in jinja date format

Tags: jinja2, getstream-io

I have `time` string which represents a time in ISO8601 format.

The formula to format to a date: `{{ time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}`

**Current output:**

```
time = 2018-01-23T08:11:58.000000

output: 2018-01-23
```

I want to divide it in 6 hours spans:

```
time = 2018-01-23T08:11:58.000000

output: 2018-01-23_1 // last "1" represents second span of 6 hours in 24 hours day (6-12)
```

What I need to add to my formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divided `hour` by `6`.

```
{{ time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}_{{ time.strftime('%H')/6 }}
```

and got results:

```
2018-01-23_1 // for hours 6-12
2018-01-23_2 // for hours 12-18
```

No idea why couldn't think this simple logic earlier.